# Maze Game Collision Detection

Tags: java, swing

I am making a Maze game right now and I've been struggling with writing the code for the collision detection. The Ball(Number 4) is supposed to move only on the sandimage(which is assigned to number 1) but should not be able to move on the white image(number 2 in the array).
This is the array I am using for the map:

```
int [] map1 = {  1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 4,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2,
                     1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2,
                     3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 };
```

And this is the code for the buttons that are assigned to the numbers in the array:

```
  for( int nCount= 0; nCount < 208; nCount++ ) //for loop which goes from 0 to 208
        {
            JGridButton[nCount] = new JButton(""); //inserts a button for every count in the for loop
            JPanelnorth.add(JGridButton[nCount]); //this line of code adds the buttons to the named panel
            JGridButton[nCount].setBorderPainted(false);
        if(map1[nCount]==1) // the image on the button will be set to sandimage, if the number in the array = 1
        {
            JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandimage);
        }
        if(map1[nCount]==2) // the image on the button will be set to whiteimage, if the number in the array = 2
        {
            JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(whiteimage);
        }
        if(map1[nCount]== 4) // the image on the button will be set to goldenball, if the number in the array = 4
        {
            JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(goldenball);
        }
        if(map1[nCount]== 3) // the image on the button will be set to sandstone, if the number in the array = 3
        {
            JGridButton[nCount].setIcon(sandstone);
        }
      }
```

Comment: I'm sorry, It looks to me the actual motion code is missing. I see the map and what appears to be a paint code. how do you intend to make the ball move through the maze? Keyboard? click on one of your buttons?

Comment: This is the code I am using to move the ball through the maze: public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {
     Object source = event.getSource();                                                          if(source == Jbuttonup)
     {
      JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompassnorth);
         JTextField3.setText("N");
         JGridButton[nPosition -16].setIcon(goldenball);
         JGridButton[nPosition].setIcon(sandimage);
         nPosition = nPosition -16; 
     }
     
 the code for down, left and right are similar to this one

Comment: 1) Instead of `208` use `map.length`. 2) Instead of multiple `if` statements, use a single `switch` statement. 3) It will be easier for you to use a `Map` between the numbers array and the buttons array. 4) You can use a `Map` between the numbers and the images.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is have it get the coordinates of the section that the ball is gonna go to. So if the user press the down arrow it gets the coordinates, checks to see if that item in the array is white and then if it is not it moves.

Also, you definitely should use a 2D array rather than a 1d array for your map so you can access the positions by x,y.
`int[][] map1 = {firstRow of stuff},{second row of stuff}, {etc};`
and then `boolean isTouchingWhite = map1[x][y] == 2;`

Comment: Hello, thank you for your anwser, but my lecturer told me that we shouldn't  use 2D arrays and stick with 1D arrays for this project. Can you use the same code for the 1D array as well? Like this boolean isTouchingWhite = map[] ==2;

Comment: I don't really know what your final product is supposed to look like... can you post a link to a screenshot of the maze the user needs to navigate?

Comment: @UmeerRama also you could make your 1d array 2d by using a clever little formula. The position on your array is equal to the x coordinate plus the y coordinate multiplied by the width of the array. In shorter form `pos = x+(y*width)` you could do `boolean isTouchingWhite = map1[x+(y*MAP1_WIDTH)]==2;`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply :( I've got an integer called nPosition, which tells the programm on which button the ball is currently on and wants to move on. Isn't it the same in principle? How do I upload a picture in the comment section?

Comment: Just upload it to an image hosting site and post a link e.g. [imgur.com](http://imgur.com)

Answer (score 0):

It appears to me you haven't checked the boundaries before moving your stone. Here is how I would do the code to move, from what you've shown:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) 
{
    Object source = event.getSource(); 
    int next = nPosition - 16;
    if(source == Jbuttonup && next >= 0 && map1[next] == 1) 
    {
        JButtoncompass.setIcon(iconCompassnorth); 
        JTextField3.setText("N");
        // update the map
        map1[next] = 4;
        map1[nPosition] = 1;
        nPosition = next; 
        // let the paint method draw the updated map.
        repaint(); 
    }
}
```

For the left check boundary, I'd implement as `(next >= 0 && (nPosition % 16) != 0)`, the right boundary check should be `(next < map1.length && (next % 16) != 0)` and the down boundary check should be  `(next < map1.length)`. The key is to check that `map1[next] == 1`